# Why are $\ln x$ and $e^x$ considered to be each others' inverses?

Tags: real-analysis, inverse-function

From my understanding the definition of a function's inverse is as follows.
Take a function $f$ which has the inverse $f^{-1}$. This would mean that $f(f^{-1}(x)) = x$ and that $f^{-1}(f(x)) = x$ for every real value for $x$. Right? And this is true for $\ln(e^x) = x$ but for $e^{(\ln x)} = x$ it only holds true for $x > 0$. Why are they still considered each others' inverse?

Comment: It's true because the range of $x\mapsto e^x$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$ is $(0, \infty)$, so of course it only makes sense for the inverse to be defined on $(0, \infty)$. Strictly speaking, your definition of inverse isn't quite right; the inverse of a function $f : X\to Y$ is defined $f^{-1} : Y\to X$.

Comment: As @Micheal Lee explained, if f:A→B then it's inverse is f−1:B→A, and these sets are not necessarily the all the real numbers. Particularly, the exponential function is not surjective over the reals (hence not inversible) but it is surjective and injective over the positive reals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, inverse functions have the other one’s domain and range.

The function $f(x) = e^x$ has a domain $x \in \mathbb{R}$ (all real numbers) and range of $y > 0$ (all positive numbers).

Therefore, $f^{-1}(x) = \ln x$ has a domain $x > 0$ and range $y \in \mathbb{R}$.

$e^{\ln x}$ being defined for $x > 0$ has to do with the domain of $\ln x$.

$(f\circ f^{-1})(x) = x$ given that $x$ lies within the domain of $f^{-1}(x)$ and that $f^{-1}(x)$ lies within the domain of $f(x)$, which is the case here if $x>0$.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two sets $A,B$ (they may be the same set, or they may not), and two functions $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A$, then $f$ and $g$ are said to be eachother's inverses if $g(f(a))=a$ for all $a\in A$ and $f(g(b))=b$ for all $b\in B$.

In this case, your two sets are the set of real numbers $\Bbb R$ and the set of positive real numbers $\Bbb R^+$.